# Image overlay using binary mask in Python using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, bit-manipulation, mask

I have the following script to open an image and create a binary mask. I need to extract the specified region from the original image using its own binary mask.

```
# Opening .tif file
org_img = cv2.imread(fn,0)
#Thresholded binary image
Triag_thresh = filters.threshold_triangle(org_img)
thresh_triag = org_img > Triag_thresh
mask = thresh_triag
plt.imshow(thresh_triag,cmap='gray')

masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(org_img, org_img, mask=mask)
```

[image]

When I run this script, I get the following error at bitwise operation

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-f57cbc97274c> in <module>
      7 plt.imshow(thresh_triag,cmap='gray')
      8 
----> 9 masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(org_img, org_img, mask=mask)

error: OpenCV(4.5.3) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'bitwise_and'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - mask data type = 0 is not supported
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mask'
```

I could not figure out why this error is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/70891237/2836621

Comment: nah, that's not it. `thresh_triag` is a numpy array of **bool**, and opencv doesn't like that (yet). use `mask = thresh_triag.astype(np.uint8)` and feed _that_ in